# How to fix a makefile that works in Dev C and Netbeans, but not in Eclipse?

Tags: c, netbeans, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Alright, this is for a school project where I am supposed to complete a skeleton program provided by the professor. Here is the makefile as provided to me:

```
db: db.o students.o courses.o enrolls.o
    cc db.o students.o courses.o enrolls.o -o db
db.o: db.c types.h students.h courses.h enrolls.h db.h
    cc -c db.c
students.o: students.c types.h students.h
    cc -c students.c
courses.o: courses.c types.h courses.h
    cc -c courses.c
enrolls.o: enrolls.c types.h students.h courses.h enrolls.h
    cc -c enrolls.c
```

Now, this worked fine in the commandline (with gcc) and in Dev C++, but when I tried to use Netbeans it threw an error, saying something about the clean command. So, I added this line:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.exe *.o
```

to the end of the file, and it worked fine (in Netbeans). But, it still won't work in Eclipse CDT. It gives this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.  Course Project          C/C++ Problem
```

So, I tried adding

```
all:db
```

to the top, but then it throws this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [db] Error 1  Course Project          C/C++ Problem
```

So, now I'm at a loss for what to do. I've Googled around, but nothing has seemed to work yet. Any ideas on how to change this makefile so it works in Eclipse?

Here is the makefile in its current (non-functional) form:

```
all:db

db: db.o students.o courses.o enrolls.o
    cc db.o students.o courses.o enrolls.o -o db
db.o: db.c types.h students.h courses.h enrolls.h db.h
    cc -c db.c
students.o: students.c types.h students.h
    cc -c students.c
courses.o: courses.c types.h courses.h
    cc -c courses.c
enrolls.o: enrolls.c types.h students.h courses.h enrolls.h
    cc -c enrolls.c
clean:
    rm -f *.exe *.o
```

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be "How do I get eclipse to produce a useful error message?"

Comment: I notice that there is no space between all: and db. Is it the same in your Makefile? Try make from command line first to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Eclipse use gnu make/gcc as a default build toolchain. So if your makefile works in a shell it should work in Eclipse. The first error you mention just points out that Eclipse build with the default command "make all". Adding 'all: db' should have corrected this problem. As @Bug Catcher said you should have a space between 'all:' and 'db'. You can also add a .PHONY statement :

```
.PHONY: all db clean

all: db
    @echo "Done !"

# [...]
```